# httpd - deny specific hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, httpd.conf

I have a webserver which I want everyone to be able to access except one host.
I modified the conf (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) and added the following:

```
<Location />
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from www.HOST.com
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't work. I tried to switch to `Order Deny,Allow`, place the `Allow from all` before the `deny`, but still it doesn't work.

When I browse to `www.HOST.com`, it can still fetch `.js` files and images from my webserver.
Maybe the check should be by the referrer? (I have no idea how to do that).

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Sincerely,
Adam.

Comment: What do you mean "browse to www.HOST.com"? This functionality is meant to be used when browsing "from" a particular client (that's why it says `Deny from`). NB In some old versions of Apache, the parameter to `Deny from` should be an IP address, not a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what `Deny` does. If you have `Deny from www.host.com`, that means someone with a browser on the actual IP that "www.host.com" is on, won't be able to access the site. What you are talking about is someone being referred to from a specific site. Unfortunately, the only way to prevent this from happening is checking the "referer" field of the request, and that can be forged, so it's not a sure way of preventing this from happening. You can do this by adding rules like this to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www.HOST.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```